# Query results in empty result

Tags: sql

I am trying the following query

```
`select
 skillmgt.*, competences.Competence_Description
 from skillmgt
 inner join competences
 on skillmgt.eid=competences.competence_id
 where eid=121 and datename(yyyy,timestamp)=2013`
```

the query runs successfully, But it returns no results although I have `eid's` that equal to some `competence_id's` and the `where` clause is also true

Actually,even without the `where` clause it does not work!

EDIT: Solved it by doing:

```
 select skillmgt.*,competences.* from competences
 join skillmgt
 on competences.competence_id=skillmgt.cid
 where skillmgt.eid=121 and datename(yyyy,skillmgt.timestamp)='2013'
```

Comment: What SQL flavor/database do you use ?

Comment: @dystroy, I solved it by changing the logic of retrieval.. a bit weird because it should have worked since the beginning .. 
thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 2):

`datename` returns a string. Depending on your SQL flavor, you should try

```
select
 skillmgt.*, competences.Competence_Description
 from skillmgt
 inner join competences
 on skillmgt.eid=competences.competence_id
 where eid=121 and datename(yyyy,timestamp)="2013"
```

Comment: Actually, even when I try without the where clause it does not show any rows !

Comment: Then we might need more information, like the tables structure and an example of rows that should match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
select
 skillmgt.*, competences.Competence_Description
 from skillmgt,competences
where skillmgt.eid = competences.competence_id
...
```